# How to combine two charts into the single PDF using ReportLab?

Tags: python, reportlab

Question : I'm generating charts using ReportLab. Charts are generated properly but into different PDF. I want to combine them into a single existing pdf.

basic structure of code is

```
class BreakdownPieDrawing():

    def firstChart():
        #code for generating first Pie chart

    def secondChart():
        #code for generating second Pie chart

if __name__=="__main__":   
    drawing1 = BreakdownPieDrawing()  
    drawing1.firstChart()
    drawing1.save(formats=['pdf'],outDir='.',fnRoot='first')

    drawing2 = BreakdownPieDrawing()  
    drawing2.secondChart()
    drawing2.save(formats=['pdf'],outDir='.',fnRoot='second')
```

for full code Snippets please refer http://www.reportlab.com/snippets/4/

This code produces two separate PDFs. How can i combine them into single PDF.

I tried this to code :

```
def makePdf(self,drawing):  
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate('hello.pdf')
    doc.build(drawing)
```

and then after I'm passing "BreakdownPieDrawing" class's object into this method. But this approach is not working.
I'm new to reportLab and python so pardon me for such a ugly code.

So the question is how to add this charts into existing pdf. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the code snippet you provided (disclaimer: I wrote ;-) ) specifically at line#33 you see

```
# adding a pie chart to the drawing   
self._add(self,Pie(),name='pie',validate=None,desc=None)
```

That lines adds the Pie chart to the drawing, you will then need to add your second chart to the same drawing you use the _add method, again like the snippet does on line#46 for adding the legend. Your drawing will have the two charts and when you save it as PDF you should get them both.

Comment: Oh Got it. Thnx a lot Sir .. :-)

Comment: Please reply to this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343382/pyrhon-reportlabs-save-2-different-graphs-in-2-different-pages. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are these two charts actually full page?  If so, you can just call for a page break between drawing the two.  Otherwise you can just adjust the coordinates so that both will fit on the page.

Alternatively, if you are doing something more complicated and will end up using Platypus, it might make sense to create a custom Flowable to render them.

Comment: thnk you very much for your reply,my question is how to add this chart into existing PDF. as the code snippets i attached is used to produce a brand new PDF. Is there any way to make this pdf as a object or somthing like tht ?? so i can use it in my existing pdf and can draw it any where and any how. or reference to some code snippets by which i get better idea of it? any idea or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thnkx